# Should I mention personal information in this thank you letter?

Tags: funding, united-states

So I got an email from my university that a donor is willing to provide me with a scholarship to help me finish my program. I don't know him and I never met him before.

I mentioned these points in my thank you letter:

**Introduction:**

- Purpose of the letter / Thank you
- Informing about the university and that I received the scholarship

**Paragraph 1:**

- How would the scholarship reflect on my education
- Appreciation
- Willing to do better

**Paragraph 2:**

- Introducing my major and all the projects that I accomplished so far.
- Excitement
- Thank you

**Last paragraph:**

- Thank you

This might sound weird but am I missing personal information? **Is it usually supposed to introduce yourself and maybe your contact information in a thank you letter?**

I want it to be professional but I never done this before and excuse me this is my first time here

Comment: Consider substituting "prepared to work hard" for "willing to do better."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I received a donor personally choosing to fund my education, I would include personal information in the thank you letter. The personal information I would include are things like "I grew up in .... I became interested in [scientific field] because..." and I would include it in the first paragraph. The reason that I feel that including personal information is appropriate is because you were personally chosen for this funding source (as opposed to applying to a scholarship committee, for example). Congrats!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will include that. How many lines do you think the letter is nice to be?

Comment: 3/4 of a page will show dedication while keeping it short.

Comment: Thanks :) What approximate font size if you don't mind? Because I am doing it hand written

Comment: 12 point. I think around 500-650 words is appropriate.